# Try/Blocks exceptions in a called function

Tags: python, recursion, exception

I have some functions which are called in a chain, on which I need introduce try/except blocks to deal with exceptions arising from a library I'm using.

I'm trying to understand if this is safe, more concretely if we can always expect that a try/except block does not see deeper try/except blocks in the flow of execution:

```
def level_two_function():

    try:
        return a[i]
    except:
        return "Exception at level 2"

def level_one_function():

    try:
        return level_two_function()
    except:
        return "Exception at level 1"

level_one_function() # 'Exception at level 2'
```

the try/except block of `level_one_function` in any condition does it ever sees any exception raised by `level_two_function`?

How is the behaviour when compared with the following situation?

```
def work(token, restrictions):

    def loop(token):
        if token.text in restrictions:
            try:
                return loop(token.nbor())
            except IndexError:
                return token
        else:
            return token

    try:
        start = token.nbor()
        return loop(start)
    except IndexError:
        #  if it has no neighbor just return it
        return token
```

Comment: There is no recursion here; nowhere does any of these functions call itself. Not that the answer would differ for a recursive call, however.

Comment: I know, i was just providing an example with one nested level. So the return exception just applies in a recursive call?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if the call is recursive or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `level_one_function()` can still see exceptions raised during `level_two_function`, if an exception was raised in the `return "Exception at level 2"` line.

That line could raise an exception if you ran out of memory, or a keyboard interrupt was sent.

However, any exceptions raised in the `try:..except` block of `level_two_function()` will be handled by that block, and won't propagate up the call stack.